How to fix height widget in Scrollbar, align animation to mobile and web, and avoid lag on website?
I have two issues with my Flutter code:

Height of the Scrollbar Widget:
The Scrollbar widget in my code has a fixed height of 10, which is causing layout issues. I need to make the height responsive or adjust it properly.

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scrollbar(
    child: GridView.builder(
      itemCount: 1,
      gridDelegate:
      const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 1),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
            height: 10, // Fixed height causing issues
            width: double.infinity,
            // ...


Aligning Animation on Mobile and Web and Avoiding Lag on Website:
I'm trying to align an animation (Timer UI) on both mobile and web devices. I've implemented ResponsiveSizer and used a conditional check based on Device.screenType to render different UI for mobile and web. However, this approach doesn't seem to work correctly, and there's a lag when the timer starts on the website.

Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
  ? Scaffold( // Mobile UI )
  : Scaffold( // Web UI )

I've tried adjusting the height values (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.715 and MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.615) to align the animation, but it doesn't make any difference on the website, and the lag persists.
How can I fix the height issue with the Scrollbar widget and properly align the animation on both mobile and web devices while avoiding lag on the website?
